# While(1) doesn't work when interrupt active

Tags: microcontroller, interrupts

I use PIC18F45K22. After getting UART RX interrupt the program doesn't go back While(1) loop. ISR runs correctly by itself. I need LED blink continuously in while(1) loop. What is missed? I tried disable interrupt after getting IRQ and enable after some time, but it didn't.

```
#define _XTAL_FREQ 16000000
#define USE_OR_MASKS

#include <p18cxxx.h>
//#include "usart.h"
//#include "i2c.h"
#include "stdint.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "config.c"
//#include "sgp30.h"
//#include "SHT2x.h"          //header file for SHT2x functions
//#include "I2C_HAL.h"        //header file for I2C hardware abstraction
//#include "System.h"         //header file for system settings
#include "LED_func.h"

#define OPENSW 1000 //Un-pressed switch value
#define TRIP 300 //Difference between pressed and un-pressed switch
#define HYST 65 //amount to change
#define PRESSED 1
#define UNPRESSED 0

void EUSART1_config(void);
void EUSART2_config(void);
void MSSP1_config(void);
void MSSP2_config(void);
void ctmu_init(void);
void GPIO_init(void);
uint8_t read_touch_button(void);
void print_ascii(uint16_t val);


uint8_t pm_array[32];    
uint16_t pm_sum = 0;
uint8_t pm_cnt = 0;
uint16_t pm_glob = 0;


uint8_t mode_glob = 0;
volatile uint8_t pm_flag=0;
  
  
void main(void) {
    
    uint8_t current_mode ;
    uint16_t current_val=0;
    int i;
    OSCCON = 0x7C; //16MHz
    //OSCCONbits.IRCF = 0b111;
    //OSCCONbits.SCS = 0b00; //primary clock
    //OSCCONbits.SCS = 0b10; //internal osc
    
    GPIO_init();
    ctmu_init();
    LED_spring(1);
    

    EUSART1_config();
    EUSART2_config();
    //MSSP1_config();
    //MSSP2_config();
    
     INTCONbits.PEIE=1; 
     INTCONbits.GIE=1; 
    
 
    while(1)
    {   
        
        
        if(pm_flag==1)
        {
                 pm_flag=0;
                 
                 print_ascii(pm_glob);    
                 
                 //mode LEDleri
                 LED_mode(read_touch_button());
                 
                 //RGB ledi
                 if(pm_glob<50)
                 {
                     LED_RGB(0);
                 }
                 else if(pm_glob<60)
                 {
                     LED_RGB(1);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     LED_RGB(2);
                 }
                 
        }
        //Display değeri
        LED_display(pm_glob);
       
        
        
    }
    
    
    return;
    
}



void ctmu_init(void)
{
 
    PIE1bits.ADIE=1; // Enables A/D interrupt

    CTMUCONHbits.CTMUEN = 0; //make sure CTMU is disabled
    CTMUCONHbits.CTMUSIDL = 0; //CTMU continues to run in idle mode
    CTMUCONHbits.TGEN = 0; //disable edge delay generation mode of the CTMU
    CTMUCONHbits.EDGEN = 0; //edges are blocked
    CTMUCONHbits.EDGSEQEN = 0; //edge sequence not needed
    CTMUCONHbits.IDISSEN = 0; //Do not ground the current source
    CTMUCONHbits.CTTRIG = 0; //Trigger Output is disabled
    CTMUCONLbits.EDG2POL = 0;
    CTMUCONLbits.EDG2SEL = 0x3; //Edge2 Src = OC1 (don?t care)
    CTMUCONLbits.EDG1POL = 1;
    CTMUCONLbits.EDG1SEL = 0x3; //Edge1 Src = Timer1 (don?t care)
    
    CTMUICON = 0b00000010; //0.55uA, Nominal - No Adjustment
    
    ADCON2bits.ADFM=1; // Results format 1= Right justified
    ADCON2bits.ACQT=1; // Acquition time 7 = 20TAD 2 = 4TAD 1=2TAD
    ADCON2bits.ADCS=2; // Clock conversion bits 6= FOSC/64 2=FOSC/32
    ADCON1bits.PVCFG0 =0; // Vref+ = AVdd
    ADCON1bits.NVCFG1 =0; // Vref- = AVss
    ADCON0bits.CHS=0; // Select ADC channel
    ADCON0bits.ADON=1; // Turn on ADC
    
    CTMUCONHbits.CTMUEN = 1; //Enable CTMU
    
}

uint8_t read_touch_button(void)
{
    uint16_t adc_val;
   
    CTMUCONLbits.EDG1STAT = 0; // Set Edge status bits to zero
    CTMUCONLbits.EDG2STAT = 0;
    CTMUCONHbits.IDISSEN = 1; //Drain any charge on the A/D circuit
    __delay_us(125);
    CTMUCONHbits.IDISSEN = 0; //Stop discharge of A/D circuit
    
    Nop(); Nop();
    CTMUCONLbits.EDG2STAT = 0; // Make sure edge2 is 0
    CTMUCONLbits.EDG1STAT = 1; // Set edge1 - Start Charge
    __delay_us(20);
    CTMUCONLbits.EDG1STAT = 0; //Clear edge1 - Stop Charge
    
    
    PIR1bits.ADIF = 0; //make sure A/D Int not set
    ADCON0bits.GO=1; //and begin A/D conv.
    while(ADCON0bits.GO); //Wait for A/D convert complete

    //adc_val = (ADRESH<<8) | ADRESL;
    adc_val = ADRES;
    print_ascii(adc_val);
     
    if(adc_val < OPENSW - TRIP)
    {
    
     mode_glob += 1;
     if(mode_glob==5)
     {
         mode_glob=0;
     }
    }
    else if(adc_val > OPENSW - TRIP + HYST)
    { 
    
    }
    
    return mode_glob;

}

void GPIO_init(void)
{
    //ANALOG
    ANSELA = 0b00000001;
    ANSELB = 0b00000000;
    ANSELC = 0b00000000;
    ANSELD = 0b00000000;
    ANSELE = 0b00000000;
    
//    PORTA = 0b00000000;
//    PORTB = 0b00000000;
//    PORTC = 0b00000000;
//    PORTD = 0b00000000;
//    PORTE = 0b00000000;
    
    //EUSART
    TRISCbits.TRISC6 = 1;
    TRISCbits.TRISC7 = 1; 
    TRISDbits.TRISD6 = 1;
    TRISDbits.TRISD7 = 1; 
    
    //MSSP
    TRISCbits.TRISC3 = 1; //SCL1
    TRISCbits.TRISC4 = 1; //SDA1
    
    TRISDbits.TRISD0 = 1; //SCL2
    TRISDbits.TRISD1 = 1; //SDA2
    
    //CAP TOUCH
    TRISAbits.TRISA0=1;
    
    //LED
    TRISAbits.TRISA1 = 0; //mode1
    TRISAbits.TRISA3 = 0; //led1
    TRISAbits.TRISA4 = 0; //led2
    TRISAbits.TRISA5 = 0; //led7
    LATAbits.LATA1 = 0;
    LATAbits.LATA3 = 1;
    LATAbits.LATA4 = 1;
    LATAbits.LATA5 = 1;
    
    
    TRISBbits.TRISB1 = 0; //grup1
    TRISBbits.TRISB3 = 0; //grup2
    TRISBbits.TRISB4 = 0; //grup3
    TRISBbits.TRISB5 = 0; //mode5
    LATBbits.LATB1 = 0;
    LATBbits.LATB3 = 0;
    LATBbits.LATB4 = 0;
    LATBbits.LATB5 = 0;
    
    
    TRISCbits.TRISC0 = 0; //BLUE
    TRISCbits.TRISC1 = 0; //RED
    TRISCbits.TRISC2 = 0; //GREEN
    TRISCbits.TRISC5 = 0; //spring led
    LATCbits.LATC0 = 0;
    LATCbits.LATC1 = 0;
    LATCbits.LATC2 = 0;
    LATCbits.LATC5 = 0;
    
    TRISDbits.TRISD2 = 0; //led3
    TRISDbits.TRISD3 = 0; //led4
    TRISDbits.TRISD4 = 0; //led5
    TRISDbits.TRISD5 = 0; //led6
    LATDbits.LATD2 = 1;
    LATDbits.LATD3 = 1;
    LATDbits.LATD4 = 1;
    LATDbits.LATD5 = 1;
    
    TRISEbits.TRISE0 = 0; //MODE2
    TRISEbits.TRISE1 = 0; //MODE3
    TRISEbits.TRISE2 = 0; //MODE4
    LATEbits.LATE0 = 0;
    LATEbits.LATE1 = 0;
    LATEbits.LATE2 = 0;
    
    
}


void MSSP1_config(void)
{
  
    SSP1STAT = 0b00000000;
    SSP1CON1 = 0b00101000;
    SSP1CON2 = 0b00000000;
    SSP1ADD=39;
    
    PIE1bits.SSP1IE = 1; 
    PIR1bits.SSP1IF = 0; 
    PIR2bits.BCL1IF = 0;        
    
    
}

void MSSP2_config(void)

{
    
    PMD1bits.MSSP1MD=0;
    PMD1bits.MSSP2MD=0;
    
    
    SSP2STAT = 0b00000000;
    SSP2CON1 = 0b00101000;
    SSP2CON2 = 0b00000000;
    SSP2ADD=39;
    
    PIE3bits.SSP2IE = 1; 
    PIR3bits.SSP2IF = 0; 
    PIR3bits.BCL2IF = 0; 
    
}


//RX only
void EUSART1_config(void)
{
    SPBRG1 = 25;
    SPBRGH1 = 0;
    
    TXSTA1bits.BRGH = 0;
    BAUDCON1bits.BRG16 = 0;
    
    TXSTA1bits.SYNC = 0;
    TXSTA1bits.TX9 = 0; 
    RCSTA1bits.SPEN = 1; 
    RCSTA1bits.CREN = 1;
    
    PIR1bits.RC1IF = 0;
    PIR1bits.TX1IF = 0;
    PIE1bits.RC1IE = 1;
    PIE1bits.TX1IE = 1;
    
}

//TX only
void EUSART2_config(void)
{
    SPBRG2 = 25;
    SPBRGH2 = 0;
 
    TXSTA2bits.BRGH = 0;
    BAUDCON2bits.BRG16 = 0;
    
    TXSTA2bits.SYNC = 0;
    TXSTA2bits.TXEN = 1; 
    TXSTA2bits.TX9 = 0; //8bit
    TXSTA2bits.CSRC = 0; //dont care
    RCSTA2bits.SPEN = 1;
    RCSTA2bits.CREN = 1;
    
        
    PIE3bits.RC2IE = 1;
    PIE3bits.TX2IE = 1;
    PIR3bits.RC2IF = 0;
    PIR3bits.TX2IF = 0;
      
}


void print_ascii(uint16_t val)
{
    uint8_t p1,p2,p22,p3,p33,p4;
        
        if (val>999)  
        {
        p1 = val / 1000 ;
        p22 = val % 1000 ;
        p2 = p22 / 100;
        p33 = p22 % 100;
        p3 = p33 / 10;
        p4 = p33 % 10;
        TXREG2 = 0x30 + p1;
        while(!TXSTA2bits.TRMT);
        TXREG2 = 0x30 + p2;
        while(!TXSTA2bits.TRMT);
        TXREG2 = 0x30 + p3;
        while(!TXSTA2bits.TRMT);
        TXREG2 = 0x30 + p4;
        while(!TXSTA2bits.TRMT);
        //LED_RGB(0);
        
        }
        else if(val>99)
        {
        p1 = val / 100 ;
        p2 = val % 100 ;
        p3 = p2 / 10;
        p4 = p2 % 10;
        TXREG2 = 0x30 + p1;
        while(!TXSTA2bits.TRMT);
        TXREG2 = 0x30 + p3;
        while(!TXSTA2bits.TRMT);
        TXREG2 = 0x30 + p4;
        while(!TXSTA2bits.TRMT);
        //LED_RGB(1);
        
        }
        
        else if(val>9)
        {
        p1 = val / 10 ;
        p2 = val % 10 ;
        TXREG2 = 0x30 + p1;
        while(!TXSTA2bits.TRMT);
        TXREG2 = 0x30 + p2;
        while(!TXSTA2bits.TRMT);
        //LED_RGB(2);
        }
        
        else
        {
        p1 = val ;
        TXREG2 = 0x30 + p1;
        while(!TXSTA2bits.TRMT);
            
        }
    
        TXREG2 = 10;
        while(!TXSTA2bits.TRMT);
        TXREG2 = 13;
        while(!TXSTA2bits.TRMT);
        
}


__interrupt() void ISR(void)
{
   
    char PM_byte;
    int k;
    uint16_t checksum;
    
        
    if(PIR1bits.RC1IF==1)                
    {
           
           //if error
            if(RCSTA1bits.OERR)
            {
                RCSTA1bits.CREN = 0;
                NOP();
                RCSTA1bits.CREN = 1;
            }
            
            //Get char UART1
            PM_byte = RCREG1;
            if(PM_byte == 0x42)
            {
                pm_sum = 0;
                pm_cnt = 0;
      
            }
            
            pm_array[pm_cnt] = PM_byte;
            pm_cnt+=1;
            if(pm_cnt==32)
            {     
                for(k=0;k<30;k++)
                {
                    pm_sum += pm_array[k];
                }
             
                checksum = (pm_array[30]<<8) + (pm_array[31]);
                pm_glob = (pm_array[6]<<8) + (pm_array[7]);
                
                if (pm_sum == checksum)
                {
                 pm_flag=1;
                 
                 //print_ascii(33);
                
                }
    
            }
 

    }      
}
```

Comment: You've enabled the transmit interrupt with `PIE3bits.TX2IE = 1;`, but you never service that interrupt in your ISR handler. So as soon as you transmit a byte, and the TX interrupt fires, it'll be stuck in the ISR handler because the TX interrupt flag is never cleared.

Comment: Thanks, In addition to UART TX also PIE1bits.ADIE=1 stucks the ISR. It was very heplful. I will also have one more question: There's 3 digit segment display code in while(1). When RX IRQ occured, disrupt the while(1) and LEDS are flashing, not work continuously. How can I get out of this situation?

Comment: You have a commented out `print_ascii(33);` line in your ISR. Is that still commented out or have you re-enabled it? The code you've written in your `print_ascii()` function is not suitable to be used from inside an ISR with all of those `while(!TXSTA2bits.TRMT);` statements, so if you've re-enabled it then that's likely your problem.

Comment: It's commented out still. But I removed the insided while(1) and read_touch_button(void) ones, it looks better.